# Testing function within same file is called

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, testing, karma-runner

I have 2 functions where one calls the other and the other returns something, but I cannot get the test to work.

Using `expect(x).toHaveBeenCalledWith(someParams);` expects a spy to be used, but I am unaware of how to spy on a function within the same file...

> Error:  : Expected a spy, but got Function.
>
> Usage: expect().toHaveBeenCalledWith(...arguments)

**Example.ts**

```
doSomething(word: string) {
   if (word === 'hello') {
      return this.somethingElse(1);
   }
   return;
}

somethingElse(num: number) {
   var x = { "num": num };
   return x;
}
```

**Example.spec.ts**

```
fake = {"num": "1"};

it('should call somethingElse', () => {
    component.doSomething('hello');
    expect(component.somethingElse).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
});

it('should return object', () => {
    expect(component.somethingElse(1)).toEqual(fake);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Example.spec.ts, just add a `spyOn(component, 'somethingElse');` as first line of your `it('should call somethingElse ...` test :

```
fake = {"num": "1"};

it('should call somethingElse', () => {
    // Add the line below.
    spyOn(component, 'somethingElse');
    component.doSomething('hello');
    expect(component.somethingElse).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
});

it('should return object', () => {
    expect(component.somethingElse(1)).toEqual(fake);
});
```

The expect method needs a Spy as parameter when used before a `toHaveBeenCalledWith` (as per the [Jasmine documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.7/matchers.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I was trying to get it working by putting `mySpy = spyOn(component, 'somethingElse');` in the `beforeEach()` section, but it wouldn't take.