# Test a depencendy function inside same file in jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

If I have a js file like:

```
  const doSomething = async (obj, time) => {
    // ...
  };

  const throttledDoSomething = (obj, time) => {
    const throttleTime = time + SOME_DELTA_VALUE;
    return throttle(() => doSomething(elem, time), throttleTime);
  };
```

How can i mock the call for `doSomething` when testing `throttledDoSomething` in jest?

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52073418/testing-function-within-same-file-is-called) that answers it for jasmine, but I would like to stick to using jest. Also if anyone has tips on best practices in situations like that, it would be appreciated.

Comment: `const mock = jest.fn((obj, time) => "bar");` then `expect(mock({a:b, 123)).toBe("bar")`

Comment: @RandyCasburn but this way it wouldn't test the function I need, but expecting a mocked value to be what was determined in the mock itself.

Comment: `expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({a:b, 123});` will verify the dependency is called correctly. That is the intent of a mock.  Otherwise, you may be confusing the term _mock_ with the term _stub_. Do you actually want to test the `doSomething()` method from within a test case for the `throttleDoSomething()` method?

Comment: so you want to mock one function while testing another function from the same file, do I see it correct?

Comment: @skyboyer exactly

Comment: it was a duplicate indeed